# PouchDb + Cordova não funcionando

Tags: android, apache-cordova, pouchdb

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando o *PouchDb* e criando aplicativos utilizando o *Cordova*.

Já testei a aplicação no *chrome, firefox, android browser, safari, blackBerry browser, app for ios, apk no blackBerry* e em todos eles funcionou corretamente.

O problema é somente no *android*, onde o *app* abre normalmente e quando o *PouchDb* começa a fazer o *sync* o aplicativo fecha sozinho sem mensagem de erro ou log algum. Já realizei vários testes em dois tablets diferentes (Android 4.1.2) e nos dois ocorre o mesmo problema.

Alguém já passou por este problema?

Preciso resolver isso urgente.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Você está utilizando o CORS? No adb não existe nenhum log ou informações com a TAG do Cordova? Pelo que vi no github deles existe um problema no WebKit do Android 4.1 e 4.2.2 e infelizmente não existe solução para isso. Mais info no link: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/504

Comment: Sim utilizando CORS. Consegui resolver aqui, é um problema com o *SqLite* + *Android*, acho que o Android não consegue gerenciar e mata a aplicação. Testei com o *WebSql* e funcionou corretamente, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizei testes em versões diferentes do Android e constatei que o problema está no Android e não na aplicação. Esta versão do Android por algum motivo quando a aplicação começa a escrever e ler muitos dados no disco, apresenta alguma falha relacionada a despejo de memória ou algo parecido fazendo com que a aplicação feche inesperadamente.
Atualizado o Android para o 4.4.2 e passou a funcionar perfeitamente.